# java - Сортировка boolean массива

Tags: java, массивы

У меня есть `boolean` массив. Как я могу отсортировать его так, чтобы сперва были значения только `false`, а после них - только `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Boolean[] array = {true, false, true, false, true, true};

    List<Boolean> sorted = Arrays.stream(array).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

    sorted.stream().forEach(f -> System.out.println(f));
```

результат

```
false
false
true
true
true
true
```

https://ideone.com/KYePDt

Плюс этого метода в том, что `stream()` можно легко заменить на `parallelStream()` для больших данных.

Comment: Не проще ли вызвать `Arrays.parallelSort()`, в который это и так упирается под капотом?

Answer (score 7):

Такую задачу однозначно нужно решать [сортировкой подсчётом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC), т.к. у нас всего два возможных значения в результате получится сложность алгоритма `O(n)`, в вашем конкретном случае можно написать вот так

```
public static boolean[] sortBooleans(boolean[] array) {
    int fc = 0;
    for(boolean b:array) if(!b) fc++;
    boolean[] narray = new boolean[array.length]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < fc; i++) narray[i] = false;
    for(int i = fc; i < narray.length; i++) narray[i] = true;
    return narray;
}
```

Обобщение на случай `m` возможных значений можно посмотреть по [ссылке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC).

Comment: строку for(int i = 0; i < fc; i++) narray[i] = false; можно убрать

Answer (score 3):

А сколько элементов в массиве? Если достаточно много, то может проще сделать  таким вот макаром

```
public boolean[] sortBooleanArray(boolean[] in) {
    int trueCount = 0;
    for (boolean b : in) {
        if (b) trueCount++;
    }
    boolean[] out = new boolean[in.length];
    boolean[] trueOut = new boolean[trueCount];
    Arrays.fill(trueOut, true);
    System.arraycopy(trueOut, 0, out, in.length - trueCount, trueCount);
    return out;
}
```

Comment: А не перебор ли это - создавать дополнительный массив и копировать из массива в массив? По-моему, проще просто выставить значение `true` в нужных элементах массива `out`. Что-то вроде такого: [пример](https://ideone.com/fCz9bJ).

Comment: Перебор - это когда в цикле вообще-то :) Если интересно - можете провести нагрузочное тестирование обоих вариантов.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что Arrays.fill и System.arraycopy могут оказаться быстрее - надо в реализацию лезть.

Answer (score 1):

Вам подойдет любой алгоритм сортировки, разница лишь в том, как их сравнивать, потому что оператор `<>` не подходит для сравнения переменных типа `boolean`:

```
boolean[] arr = {true, false, true, true, false};
for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i] && !arr[j]) {
            arr[i] = false;
            arr[j] = true;
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

**Вывод**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В рамках оптимизации имеет смысл `if (arr[i])` вынести за внутренний цикл, а во внутреннем `if` добавить `break`. [Пример](https://ideone.com/ybK4xu).

Comment: @Regent в рамках оптимизации стоит написать нормальный алгоритм за O(n), а не тот что работает за O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

Более классический вариант, с использованием одного цикла.

```
int current = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   if (array[i]) continue;

   array[i] = true;
   array[current] = false;
   current++;
}
```

Comment: `current` можно тоже в for внести

Comment: каким образом? нам нужно запоминать крайнюю левую позицию для вставки, при итерировании по массиву.

Comment: я имел ввиду определение: `int i = 0,current = 0;`

Comment: это безусловно, вкусовщина, но я так не люблю писать - читается плохо

Comment: зато потом не болтается переменная которая используется только в цикле

Comment: ну так то да. А что если этих переменных несколько, все тащить в for? не вариант же.

Comment: почему нет? раз они используются _только_ в цикле, вполне нормально определить их в блоке инициализации цикла

Comment: @Grundy усложнение стандартной конструкции, влечет увеличение времени на понимание и разбор, того как это работает, просто банально потому что такое редко используется.отсюда хромает читабельность кода.

Comment: @Grundy для меня всегда эталоном была стандартная библиотека java. Понимаю что там есть места с плохим дизайном и пр. Но в целом это очень хорошая библиотека. Если посмотреть исходники то там как правило пишут так как я описал. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java?av=f#1754

Comment: @Grundy даже есть обратная ситуация, когда из for выносили сложное определение переменной. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java?av=f#1661

Comment: Всего лишь дело привычки.

Answer (score 0):

Не использовать в production'e)

```
boolean[] array = {true, false, true, false, true, true};
Stream
     .generate(
            new Supplier<Boolean>() {
                  private int index = 0;
                  @Override
                  public Boolean get() {
                     return array[index++];
                  }
             })
     .limit(array.length)
     .sorted()
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без создания нового массива.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean[] arr = new boolean[10];
    Random r = new Random();
    int counter = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        arr[x] = r.nextBoolean(); // заполнение массива случайными значениями boolean
    }

    for (boolean x : arr) {
        if (!x) counter++; // подсчет количества значений false в изначальном массиве
    }

    Arrays.fill(arr, 0, counter, false); // заполнение первых значений массива согласно подсчета количества false значений
    Arrays.fill(arr, counter, arr.length, true); // остальные элементы массива заполнятся значениями true
}
```